google api -Distance matrix API Billing with SKU
I am trying to manage google api billing for distancematrix - route api. I am wondering that after my free trial can i be able to get 200$ as free credit? I mean I will try to improve a porject to get distance between locations and Pricing system is confusing for me.
I want to clarify the issue. As I understand system charge around $10 per 1.000 request and giving free $ 200 per month so if I send 30.000 request per month we will be charged around $100 İs it correct?
One more question:
I am planning to use this kind of product :
1-
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=41.096043%2c28.996184&mode=driving&origins=41.043268%2C29.012375&key=MYAPIKEY
this is a SKU I think.
2-
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626&origins=40.6655101%2C-73.89188969999998&key=MYAPIKEY
What about this ? These two request will be charged same? or

one is 1 destination * 1 origin as 1 request and
one is 4 destination * 1 origin as 4 request

Best Regards, Uğur Demir
I was tried to find a clue from https://console.cloud.google.com/billing but It did not update my requests and did not change charge part. May be data is updating per day or I might need to end my free trial. I really do not know.nd
